# Is there any way to unit test xamarin.forms app and use the test set for c.i. with app center?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration, automated-tests, visual-studio-app-center

I am new to testing for xamarin forms and unit testing in general. I've created an unit test project for my xamarin.forms app, I wrote some basic unit tests and I was wondering if I can run these test using appcenter and continuos integration. 
I can run these tests only on windows pc locally, but my ci server runs on Mac so I was wondering what approach can I use to unit test my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we managed to run the unit test by adding a Bash Shell script and invoking the nunit console

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono ../../../../NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/nunit-console.exe 

APPName_Test/bin/Debug/APPName_Test.dll
```

later edit : report results from vsts
[image]

Comment: I'm curious to hear how you handled the results of the tests. Did you e-mail them anywhere? How did you know if a test failed?

Comment: we just used the 'publish testet results' task inside vsts pipeline that give a visual result, I also edited my answer to see that

Answer (score 5):

To run unit tests in your Xamarin builds in AppCenter you can use a post-build script.

You can find an example for executing NUnit tests [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/troubleshooting/xamarin#i-want-to-run-unit-tests-for-my-xamarin-application-how-can-i-do-that), and more details on how to add a post-build script can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/index#post-build).

Comment: thank you for your hints @G.sharada I'll try to write the script specific for my environemnt and get back to you!